# Python counting down to a series of times every day

Tags: python, tkinter, time

My goal is to create a countdown that will display the minutes and seconds remaining until a specific time of day and then, when that's reached, count down to the next one.

What I have so far will countdown to a specific date and time using datetime.datetime and then stop.

I currently have two problems:  How to count down using time, not datetime so that it will be the same every day (i.e. countdown to noon every day, not countdown to noon on a specific date). My second problem is how to move on to the next time to count to (I assume that's a matter of just pulling a new time when seconds_left = 0 but I'm not sure).

Here's where I'm at so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
import time
import datetime

global endTime 

def quit(*args):
    root.destroy()

def show_time():
    # Get the time remaining until the event
    remainder = endTime - datetime.datetime.now()
    # remove the microseconds part
    remainder = remainder - datetime.timedelta(microseconds=remainder.microseconds)
    # Show the time left
    txt.set(remainder)
    # Trigger the countdown after 1000ms
    root.after(1000, show_time)

# Use tkinter lib for showing the clock
root = Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.configure(background='black')
root.bind("x", quit)
root.after(1000, show_time)

# Set the end date and time for the countdown
endTime = datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 19, 9, 0, 0)

fnt = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=60, weight='bold')
txt = StringVar()
lbl = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=txt, font=fnt, foreground="green", background="black")
lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You just want to have it count down to the same time every day and then once it reaches zero stare the count over for the next day correct? That said `global endTime` is not doing what you think its doing. As it is now your `global` is not doing anything for you.

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` works just fine. What you need is a conditional statement in your `show_time` function to update your `endTime`.

Example using `datetime` with `now()` and `year`, `month`, `day` to build the next `endTime`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
import datetime as dt


def quit(*args):
    root.destroy()


def show_time():
    global endTime
    remainder = endTime - dt.datetime.now()
    remainder = remainder - dt.timedelta(microseconds=remainder.microseconds)

    if remainder.total_seconds() < 0:
        y = dt.datetime.now().year
        m = dt.datetime.now().month
        d = dt.datetime.now().day
        endTime = dt.datetime(y, m, d, 9, 0, 0) + dt.timedelta(days=1)

    txt.set(remainder)
    root.after(1000, show_time)


root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.configure(background='black')
root.bind("x", quit)
root.after(1000, show_time)
endTime = dt.datetime(2017, 9, 19, 9, 0, 0)
fnt = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=60, weight='bold')
txt = tk.StringVar()
lbl = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=txt, font=fnt, foreground="green", background="black")
lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
root.mainloop()
```